# pass input from one function to another in python

Tags: python

I am not sure of what the best way of passing a variable to a function is, within python.

```
def userouput():
    print(userin)

def userinput():
    userin = raw_input("Enter: ")
    userouput(userin)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    userinput()
```

This gives me a:

```
TypeError: userouput() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: You don't say that `userouput()` is getting any parameters

Comment: Check this [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) about defining functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an input parameter.

```
def userouput(toprint):
    print(toprint)

def userinput():
    userin = raw_input("Enter: ")
    userouput(userin)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    userinput()
```

Comment: Ah I see! So 'toprint' can be anything, it does not need to be the same name  as the variable that is sent (userin)?

Comment: That's correct. You can pass any value/variable into `userouput()` and inside `userouput()` `toprint` will hold that value.